# flutter - pubspec.yaml doesn't update

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am try to add some fonts to my app and when ever I add them in pubsbec.yaml it give "get packages" and then stop with no result.
also when I tried to add another packages the same happens..
another thing that when I run the app **it says**

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 66, column 4: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
   ╷
66 │    fonts:
   │    ^
   ╵
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file
```

"Note: I checked the spaces and the spelling and they are true"
how I can do it correctly?

part of pubspec file

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

   fonts:
    - family: Ranga
       fonts:
         - asset: fonts/Ranga-Regular.ttf
         - asset: fonts/Ranga-Bold.ttf
           style: Bold
           weight: 700
```

**this is how I used the fonts:**

```
Text("Recipe Name",                  
        style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black54,
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        fontFamily: "Ranga"
      ),
```

Comment: Can you post your pubspec yaml here? It's likely just a typ0 or something small like that

Comment: ok but should I post all of the file or just the fonts?

Comment: can you post the part of the code where you added the fonts?

Comment: okay I did, but I think the problem is in the yaml file, because it does not completed getting packages

Comment: Can you write the pubspec in a block of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the spaces, they are important in `.yaml` files. The result should be like bellow image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It is really worked!
could you please show me an example how to add "transparent image" package in dependencies in yaml file?

Comment: Check this link: https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_image/install @AbrarLasebai